# Oracle: OBIEE - standard deviation

Tags: oracle, obiee

I need to calculate the standard deviation for the numeric variable "amount" by the factors: "Area", "Category", "Subcategory" as a function of "Day".

For more detalis see the figure below:

[image]

I already cheched on Google and ask in StackOverfolw how to solve it, but with out success.

Can some of you help me?

It is really easy to do in Excel, Python, R, SPSS, SAS, but here in OBIEE seems to be impossible.. There is no solution also checking online... but unfortunately I have to use this awful tool.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Andrea

Comment: Can you sum the amounts, then take the StdDev of that summed column using the StdDev function provided by OBIEE? I am no stats master so I do not know if this changes the value or not by summing the values first then taking the StdDev, but I don't know how you would show it in one column otherwise...

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your help. I already calculated the sum of amounts. But is not possible to calculate standard deviation from total amount. To obtaint standard deviation you have to do:

Comment: root square (xi- x)/n

Comment: where xi is each value of amount, x the average of amount, n is the sample size

Comment: But there is a functionSTDDDEV in OBIEE tthat do that automatically. The problem is that it give me back a value (I don't understand how is calculated) for esch day... that is crazy.. stddev is a single value and represent the variability of the data.

Comment: In my case say to me how is variable "amount" for the "days"considered. So, how is it possible to obtain it?

Comment: Is crazy, such a simple thing without simple solution... I hate OBIEE but I need to use it.